Finding the noise due to circuit elements
I am trying to find out the noise referred at the input. Here is how I went about this. I started about by adding up all the current noises due to all elements at output, \$4KTR_F + 4KTR_D +  8KT(g_{m_1} + g_{m_2})/3\$ and then used this expression to find voltage output noise by multiplying by \$R_{out}^2\$, and then dividing by \$(g_{m_1}\times R_{out})^2\$ (That is the gain, not sure about the output transconductance though, is it \$g_{m_1}\$?). I have taken \$r_{o_1}\$ and \$r_{o_2}\$ to be infinite. 

What makes you think that the noise of $R_F$ and $M_1$ flow entirely to the output?

Actually I think the looking down impedance from the drain of M1 is parallel combination of RF and a large resistance (from M1's ro) is essentially RF, making the entire current going into output from RF. (This is similar to a cascode, yet different)

Am I right in this?

It seems to me that the presence of feedback loops complicates the port impedances. The noise of $R_F$ may see a different current division than the case without feedback. We need to write the derivation carefully to see if that is the case.

@a360pilot I quick question about your edit. From a first glance it looks good, but gm1*Rout^2 isn't the same as $(g_{m_1}\times R_{out})^2$. Can you vouch that this edit is correct?

@Velvet The gain of the circuit is $g_{m_1}R_{out}$. The noise must be divided by the square of that. The author can verify that this indeed was their intent.

I have edited...

Further, I have tried writing the derivation by dividing the current..Still I am getting same result, which I feel might be wrong. Can you please write a derivation.
